# How I take value from menu bar using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am very new in JavaScript but I want to solve this problem.

My code is this:

JavaScript :

```
function win(anchor) {
    var value = anchor.getAttribute('value');  
    var html = anchor.innerHTML;  
    document.write(value);
    document.write(html);
    }
```

HTML :

```
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#1" onclick="win(this)">QUANTITATIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2" onclick="win(this)">REASONING</a></li>               
        <li><a href="#3" onclick="win(this)">ENGLISH</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4" onclick="win(this)">GENERAL KNOWLADGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5" onclick="win(this)">COMPUTER</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and I want to know how using Javascript I get the value of that menu bar option that I recently click .
Mean what ever menu I click I get the value in a variable.

Comment: Nothing here has a 'value' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I created this example -

```
function win(anchor) {
    var html = anchor.innerHTML;  
    console.log(html);
}
```

Which works in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/2XD2C/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can just pass it to the method:

```
<li><a href="#1" onclick="win(this, 'QUANTITATIVE')">QUANTITATIVE</a></li>
```

it depends on your application

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementById('nav').children[1][text]);
```

Comment: You should never use alert for troubleshooting. It is better to use console.log(). Beside, the OP asked how to get the info with a click.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use event handling and unobtrusive JavaScript instead of the `onclick=""` attribute.  Here is a example using jQuery and it's `.click()` function. This will also dynamically work if your navigation will have elements added later, or different on other pages.

```
$('#nav li').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var value = $(this).find('a').html();
        $('#result').html(value);
    }); 
});
```

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/8jdKy/)